# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before error

Tags: objective-c, ios, list, specifier

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NotepadViewController.h"
#import "NotesTableViewController.h"
#import "NoteInformationTransferProtocol.h"

@interface NotesViewController : UIViewController <NoteInformationTransferProtocol>
{
    UITextField *_noteTitleTextField;
    UIButton *_addButton;
    UITextField *_description;
    UIView *_notesTableView;

    NotepadViewController * _notepadVC;
    NotesTableViewController *_noteTableVC;        
}
```

I am getting the error "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before NotepadViewController" on "NotepadViewController * _notepadVC;" I already imported that class' header so it should detect it as a type, right?

Comment: just clean and build again

Answer (score 0):

That error normally occurs when you haven't added a framework or file to your target, is "NotepadViewController.h" in the target you are building?

In xCode 4 you can check this by expanding the "Compile Sources" section in Build Phases.
In xCode 3 you can use "Get info" to see what targets that file is included (if my memory serves me true)

Comment: It is in there. I used a forward class declaration for "NotepadViewController" and it worked. I guess it has something to do with cyclical declarations. I am reading up more on it.